# How to make the style is applied

Tags: jquery, coding-style

How to make the style is applied only to the chosen object, and not all at once?

```
 $('#add_text').mousedown
        (
            function() 
            {                              
                $('#add_text').css('background-color', 'blue'),                               
    $('#template').prepend('<div id="text_frame"><input class="input_text"/></div>'),

                $('div#text_frame').attr("class", function (arr) {return "nomber" + arr;}),

                $('div#text_frame').mousedown(function(){$('div#text_frame').addClass('select_text_frame');}),

                $('#text_frame').draggable('enable'), 
     $('#text_frame').draggable({containment: '#template', distance: 1});     
            }       
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to modify only the element that invoked the event in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add_text').mousedown(function() {

        // the this keyword references the element where the mousedown
        // event has occurred
        $(this).css(...);

    });

});
```

Comment: I do not understand how it should work. Here's what happens when I press the button and add items
<div id="text_frame" class="nomber0 ui-draggable select_text_frame"> <input class="input_text"> </ div>
<div id="text_frame" class="nomber1 ui-draggable select_text_frame"> <input class="input_text"> </ div>
<div id="text_frame" class="nomber0 ui-draggable select_text_frame"> <input class="input_text"> </ div>

Styles 'select_text_frame' apply to all items added. But should only apply to the item selected.